# English to predicate- and vs imply

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, quantifiers

"Some student in this class hass taken a course in java".
First we decided that U is domain.
we defined S(x) to be x is student in class. And J(x) to be x has taken java.
The solution is :$\exists$ x(S(x) $\land $J(x))
But why $\exists$ x(S(x) $\rightarrow$ J(x)) is not correct, and how is it translated to english.

Comment: Or make the domain the students in the class.  Then the statement becomes $\exists x(J(x))$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The assertion $\exists x (S(x)\to J(x))$ would translate to English as "There exists some $x$ such that if $x$ is a student, then $x$ has taken a course in Java." This is not the same as the desired assertion, as there is no guarantee that such $x$ is a student, so it remains possible for no student in the class to have taken a course in Java.

If you really want to pursue this idea, you could write something like $\exists x( S(x) \land (S(x)\to J(x)))$, but this is somewhat silly.